# Angular 2 : No provider for (2.0.0.0)

Tags: angular, module

I have recently migrated to Angular 2 RC6 and now to 2.0.0.

I have a module that is injecting modules from another module.

The module declaration code :

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { AdminAppComponent } from './Components/admin-app.component';

import { Module2 } from "./module2/module2";



@NgModule({
    imports: [BrowserModule, Module2],
    declarations: [AdminAppComponent],
    bootstrap: [AdminAppComponent],
    providers: []
})
export class AdminAppModule {
}
```

The component code :

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core";

import { TestService } from "./../module2/services/TestService";
@Component({
    selector: "yadm-app",   
    templateUrl: "/templates/admin/app/admin-app.tpl.html"
})


export class AdminAppComponent {


    constructor(private ser: TestService) {


    }
}
```

The imported module (Module2) code:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import {TestService } from "./Services/TestService";

@NgModule({
    imports: [BrowserModule],
    declarations: [],
    bootstrap: [],
    providers: [{ provide: TestService, useClass: TestService }]
})
export class Module2 { }
```

and the service code :

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class TestService {
    getText(): string {
        return "texxxt";
    }
}
```

I got the error : "No provider for TestService". Knowing that it was correctly working in RC5.

I have noticed also that TestService.js is loading twice.

So, what's going on ?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think that after struggling for several days, I have found then answer !

It's all about capital letters in imports.

So when I write in typescript:

```
import {AdminHomeComponent} from "./components/admin-home.component";
import {AdminHomeComponent} from "./Components/admin-home.component";
```

angular 2 treats this as two separate files and triggers two get queries for loading the file !!!

The consequences after are very strange such as components not recognized as parts of modules and the famous messaging stating that there is no provider for a given service.

Thanks all !

Comment: lol, you need better ide/editor to automatically check those :D

Comment: I use VS 2015 and VS Code and both tools did not suggest anything

Comment: Are you using webpack and osx? That will be an issue.

Answer (score 0):

I tested your code and it is working.

I also just updated my testing setup from RC6 to 2.0.0. I did encounter issue with typings and packages. I did following to fix:

- Check `package.json` for Angular2 packages version
- Deleting `node_modules` and `typings` directories
- Run `npm install` and `typings install`

Comment: It has a very random behavior. It works fine at first then when I add other services, it does not recognize provided services anymore. I think it deals with the folder structure.

Answer (score 0):

For **singleton** service, you should inject service into Main **AdminAppMoudle**.
This way is will be shared among all feature modules. If you want to have a separate layer for common *services*,*directives* and *pipes*, you should go ahead with **SharedModule** feature available in Angular2.

```
import { TestService } from "./../module2/services/TestService";
@NgModule({
    imports:      [BrowserModule, Module2],
    declarations: [AdminAppComponent],
    bootstrap:    [AdminAppComponent],
    providers:    [TestService ]   //<------here. This will create a singleton service. Probably now its fine If you remove its reference for other feature module.
})
export class AdminAppModule {
}
```